# Repulsive component of intermolecular interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

Intermolecular interaction mainly consists of 2 components:

(a) Dipole vs dipole (permanent & induced), which is more likely to be attractive

(b) Pauli exclusion, which is always repulsive

The Lennard-Jones potential assigns the empirical $r^{-12}$ form to the latter component, which is not exactly accurate. The Buckingham $\exp$ form is an alternative form, but still seems a bit overly-simplified. So what are some better ways to determine the Pauli exclusion component of intermolecular interaction (apart from *ab inito* methods)? Thanks!